# Drupal view horizontal layout of rows

Tags: responsive-design, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm new to Drupal theming and have been tasked with displaying a list of articles on a front page. I have created a view and also created the custom view templates for possible overiding of the styles and markup. I have the responsive markup ready for the Drupal article contents to be displayed in. The current view displays the article image, title and body as a vertical list, I am trying to display them horizontally using the given markup. I have spent a good few hours trying to work out a way to do this but without success, any help would be appreciated. The layout is as follows:

[image]

The markup can be found here:

```
<section class="category-row people-row container">
    <h1><a href="#">Category</a></h1>
    <div class="row">
    <!-- medium article format-->
    <article class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 article-medium pull-left">              <figure><a href="#"><img src="http://xxxx" alt="REPLACE THIS WITH        STORY TITLE"></a></figure>
        <div class="teaser">
            <h2><a href="#">xyz</a></h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <!--small article format-->
    <article class="col-md-4  col-xs-6 article-small pull-right mpu-holder">
        <h2 class="hide">Advert</h2>
        <div>
            <img src="images/mpu.jpg" width="300" height="250" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </article>

    <!--small article format-->
    <article class="col-md-4  col-xs-6 article-small pull-right">
        <figure><a href="#"><img src="http://xxxx" alt="REPLACE THIS WITH STORY TITLE"></a></figure>
        <div class="teaser">
            <h2><a href="#"> Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod sem malesuada magna mollis euismod</a></h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <!-- link to category listing page-->
    <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">
        <a href="#" class=" more-link">More people stories &#8594;</a>
    </div>

  </div> <!--end row-->

</section> <!-- end container -->
```

Thanks

Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal might be best achieved by creating 2 views (or more precisely, two displays for your view).

- One display for the main area - it can be set to display the first result only.
- One display for the sidebar. In the second view you can stick your advert in the header region, and then output that view as a block. Set it to skip the first result, which will be displayed by the main view.

You can then embed each of those displays within [panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) and feed each one a different context. That will allow you to add as many of these "sets" to your page as you wish, each displaying content from a different taxonomy term.

Comment: "Or is it that each set of 2 should look like that?"  There will be a set like that for 4 different categories. Other sets will appear below with slightly different layout e.g. two small left and one large article on right.

Comment: Added more info based on your answer. Don't forget to upvote and accept.

Comment: Will give it a go, Is there a way to access the individual field values so I can control the markup that surrounds it? e.g. the main image needs to be contained in a <figure> element? I will not forget to upvote and except

Comment: Yes you can override the individual markup for each field by specifying an override template. Click on the "theming" button in your view to get started with that.

Comment: So, what I ended up going with was 4 views for each of the different layout. Related to each of these views I created two customised view templates files for each of these views. e.g. views-view-fields--frontpage-bottom-view.tpl and views-view-unformatted--frontpage-bottom-view.tpl. I also used the Clean block module to reduce the amount of surrounding Drupal markup. Thanks for the advice, I will definitely look into panels in the near future